# Consistent UI with different actions

Tags: selection, consistency

I've got a bit of a dilemma and was wondering if you could help.

In a checkout flow the user has a choice between collection of tickets at the store, or from a kiosk in a complex.

The store select screen is OK:

- User can select store straight away or view further details
- User makes a selection
- Selection is highlighted
- User proceeds using button below options

[image: Store select screen]

The problem comes when the user needs to select a kiosk at the complex to collect tickets.
I can't see a way that the user can actively select a kiosk, with feedback highlighting the active choice. If they select a different kiosk as the same complex there is little visual cue.

There are two many kiosks per complex for radio buttons.

Have you any suggestions about I might approach this?

Many thanks.

[image: Selecting kiosk at complex]

Comment: why do you need to select a kiosk, cant they just select the complex?

Comment: They do also need to select a specific kiosk for ticket pickup.

Comment: oh its a manned kiosk!? :D

Comment: :) Yes, sorry! A person physically hands over tickets after security check.

Comment: oh, i thought they were like auto kiosks... that's why I was quite surprised!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you are showing too much information at once.

I would first have the user select a complex, and only then show a way to select a kiosk.  That way it will be clear which complex is selected.  The interface you show is confusing.  Why show several complexes at once?  What happens if a user selects kiosks at two different complexes?

I would do the same thing with store, as well: Have a list with only key information that differentiates the stores (such as distance from location or a recognizable part of the address, like city/neighborhood).  Only show detailed information like hours once a store has been selected.

Comment: Thank you, Dan1111. 

Just to clarify - on the store screen I don't anticipate showing all that information at once. Users can toggle open the extra information for store hours and contact details.

I shall revisit the complex screen though - I think you are right that they should choose a complex first, then the kiosk is just an option perhaps. Fortunately, they will never need to choose more than one kiosk!

Answer (score 0):

A quick thanks to Dan and Igor. You asked the right questions when I was in the midst of iteration blindness!

Solution seems to work best:

- Select complex with radio to reveal kiosk drop down.
- Upon selecting kiosk, kiosk details are revealed, background is highlighted.

So user has feedback at every step. 
Thanks again. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Although it sounds like you've found a solution that works for you, I think you might further aid your users by providing a diagram of the kiosk layout. This would provide a users with a way to visually orient themselves when it comes time for pickup. A user could also print it out and take it with them if they like.